# HTTPS is not working with domain name or static IP but works fine with local IP

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, jboss-4.2.x

I am new to SSL and trying to enable with one of our running project.

I enabled HTTPS in local server and live server both place it works fine with local IP address. But when I try to run with domain name or static IP it shows that the connection timed out.

Example:

I created key store by following command. and .cer file from the CA.

Generate a Java keystore and key pair

```
keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Generate a certificate signing request (CSR) for an existing Java keystore

```
keytool -certreq -alias mydomain -keystore keystore.jks -file mydomain.csr
```

Import a root or intermediate CA certificate to an existing Java keystore

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file Thawte.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

Also my server.xml is like this:

```
    <Connector port="80" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
     maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="1" />


 <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
          clientAuth="false"
      strategy="ms"
          address="${jboss.bind.address}"
          keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/cert/keystore.jks"
          keystorePass="isq+bpo" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

In my web.xml I have given security constraints as confidential

I am running my Jboss 4.2.2 ga with

```
run -b 0.0.0.0
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am wrong.

It works fine if I try to access as

```
https://a.b.c.d/ctxname
```

but doesn't work if try to access as

```
https://www.mydomain.info/ctxname
```

Can it be any firewall issue - we are using Sonicwall?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the entries in the SsL certificate. As you might be accessing using IP theuntrusted warning will be reported. Address the URL with the domain name instead of IP. In Browser click on the certificate information to get more details on the certificate. Also the root certificate used might not be trusted by the browser. Add the root certificate to trusted certificate by browser.
.
Pramod

Comment: Thanks for your answers- I got solution as there was Firewall blocking the request. Once firewall has been reconfigured it works fine.